# An important corollary of Hahn - Banach Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

Let $X$ a normed linear space. Denote with $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}\;\text{or}\;\mathbb{R}$ Suppose that

(1)$\;M$ is a closed subspace of $X$;

(2)$\;x_0\in X\setminus M$;

(3)$\;d=\text{dist}(x_0, M)=\inf\{\lVert x_0-m\rVert\;:\; m\in M\}$.

Then exists $\Lambda\in X^*$ such that $$\Lambda(x_0)=d,\quad \Lambda|_M=0\quad\text{and}\quad \lVert\Lambda\rVert_{X^*}=1.$$

$\textit{Proof}$

Observe that $d>0$ since $M$ is closed. Define $M_1=\text{span}\{M,x_0\}$. Then each $x\in M_1$ can be written as $x=m_x+t_x x_0$ for same $m_x\in M$ e $t_x\in \mathbb{F}$ and since $x_0\notin M$ this representation is unique.

Define $\lambda\colon M_1\to \mathbb{F}$ as $\lambda(x)=t_xd$. Observe that $\lambda$ is linear, $\lambda|_M=0$, and $\lambda(x_0)=d.$ If $x\in M_1$ e $t_x\ne 0$, then we have that $-m_x/t_x\in M$.
Then,
$$\lVert x\rVert_X=\Vert t_x x_0+m_x\rVert_X=\lvert t_x\rvert \bigg\lVert x_0-\bigg(\frac{-m_x}{t_x}\bigg)\bigg\rVert_X\ge\lvert t_x\rvert d.$$

If $t_x = 0$ (so $x\in M$), this is still true.

Hence, $$\lvert\lambda(x)\rvert=\lvert{t_x}\rvert d \le\lVert x\rVert_X\quad\text{for all}\;x\in M_1.$$

Therefore $\lambda$ is continuous on $M_1$ and $\lVert\lambda\rVert_{M_1^*}\le1.$

On the other hand, exist vectors $m_n\in M$ such that $\lVert x_0-m_n\rVert_X\to d$ for $n\to \infty$.

Since $\lambda|_M=0$, we have that
$$d=\lambda(x_0)=\lambda(x_0-m_n)\le\lVert x_0-m_n \rVert_X\lVert\lambda\rVert_{M_1^*}\to d\lVert\lambda\rVert_{M_1^*}.$$

Therefore $\lVert\lambda\rVert_{M_1^*}\ge 1.$
Then we have $$\lVert\lambda\rVert_{M_1^*}=1.$$

For a Corollary of Hahn Banach Theorem, exists $\Lambda\in X^*$ such that $$\Lambda|_{M_1}=\lambda\quad\text{and} \quad\lVert\Lambda\rVert_{X^*}=\lVert\lambda\rVert_{M_1^*}=1.$$

Since $x_0\in M_1$ and $M\subseteq M_1$ we have  $\Lambda(x_0)=\lambda(x_0)=d$ e $\Lambda|_M=\lambda|_M=0.$

Is everything formally correct?

Comment: I think everything is correct.

Comment: @jack why did you put a bounty on this? what more needs to be said (in addition to what justdropped in said)?

Comment: I got the wrong post, sorry!